# How to upload file to gcp using java and accessToken?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) using Java and an access token. I have generated an access token and want to use it for authentication in my Java program.

I have the following components:

- An access token in string format.
- A GCS bucket where I want to upload the file.
- The name I want to give to the uploaded file in the bucket.
- The local file I want to upload.

Comment: And do you want to use the raw APIs, or the client libraries?

Comment: i want to use the client libraries

Comment: Why don't you let the client library generate the token for you? Can you share more about your context?

Comment: so I have a service that will generate the access token with expiry time. I need to use that to upload file to GCP.